# Integrating with Dynamics 365 Online Web API Prompting For Credentials

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, office365

Our client has asked us to integrate with their CRM (Microsoft Dynamics 365) from their e-commerce website in order to update customer information after a purchase.

We have been given the following documentation URL for the integration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327838%28v%3dcrm.8%29

We've managed to get this working to the point where the application loads up a prompt asking for our Dynamics 365 username and password.

This is obviously not what we want.

Ideally we would problematically enter the username and password to retrieve the bearer token which will allow us to make subsequent requests to the relevant endpoints to update order information.

We can't seem to find any coherent documentation that explains how to do this. This seems such a trivial task but apparently so difficult.

Has anyone had any experience implementing a similar solution? Or have any pointers of where we should look next?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think what you want is a security risk.  If your program got user name and password you can then store the username and password.  Microsoft know this and wants to keep username and password from hackers who are trying to spoof the website.

Comment: @jdweng There are ways for us to store the credentials securely. Isn't this just typical web api integration stuff? We can't have a popup showing on the website to end users..

Comment: Microsoft wants a direct connection to client that the can use SSL/TLS to securely get credentials.  You are trying to intervene in this process.

Comment: @jdweng So are you suggesting programmatic integration with Dynamics CRM isn't possible then?

Comment: Only after the authorization is completed.

Comment: @jdweng I think I've managed to get further with this. the OAuth protocol is not appropriate for what we're wanting here and we have been sent incorrect information from the customers dynamics consultant re the integration instructions.

But FYI - I have never integrated with a web API using REST where my code has had to manually enter a username and password in a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link that solved our issue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/quick-start-console-app-csharp